# How to reduce Laravel array validation error to a single message

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm trying to make sure that all data in a required associative array is [validated](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules), but only a single error message appears. The problem with the code below is that the same error message is repeated for each missing field.

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'   => 'required',
            'data.foo' => 'required',
             'data.bar' => 'required'

        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'You need a title!',
            'data.*'        => 'All your datas are belong to us & required'
        ];
    }
}
```

I would like a solution that is contained in the `CustomRequest` class.

The submitted form would contain elements like this:

```
<input name="data[foo]" type="text">
<input name="data[bar]" type="text">
```

Both of the elements `foo` and `bar` would be required. But if neither were entered a single error would appear.

Comment: What do you mean by all elements in an array? How many should there be? Is the array associative? Provide a sample of an input array.

Comment: Laravel can't possibly know what keys should be in the array. You will have to manualy add the keys if you want them to be required.

Comment: Do you require the `data` parameter to be an array and not empty? Then the correct rule would be `'data' => 'required|array'` and the message `'data.required' => 'The data array should not be empty'`. This way you can only pass a non-empty array.

Comment: @Bogdan I have clarified the form input.

Comment: @Jerodev That's not so. Laravel has a `foo.*` validation rule specifically to deal with arrays.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you cannot make the fields required because Laravel couldn't possibly know what fields should be there.

Comment: @Jerodev I see your point. Doh! I've edited question.

Comment: So you want a single message to appear when no array items are sent in the request, as opposed to individual messages for each array key? (also unlike @Jarodev specified, your `'data.*' => 'required'` rule is perfectly valid, and works without explicit key names and would return as expected two messages for each key: `"The data.foo field is required."` and `"The data.bar field is required."` if the values were empty).

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, that's correct. Just one error ''All your datas are belong to us & required" should either or both inputs be empty.

Comment: Could you please post how you are displaying the errors? Are you displaying them in a foreach loop?

Comment: @user10341554 The display is a sitewide Vue instance. The solution must be contained in the $error messagebag.

Comment: @Jerodev I've thought about this again. Laravel would know what fields should be there because they'd be simply inside the Request instance. request()->get('data') would contain all the elements that were in the original form, and if any one of them was empty Laravel could throw a validation error. This of course would make more sense with an associative array (which wasn't clear on my original posting of the question).